# Ask for UAC before opening a Windows folder

Tags: windows, permissions, uac

I want to create a folder where I can only open it, or its contents, by first accepting the UAC prompt.

I have a personal computer, where my account is an admin account, and most programs run under my user, so I want to restrict any program to reading the contents of this folder. I don't want to go into the trouble of creating several new users or groups, or changing my user's permission, in order to achieve this.

I have managed to change the folder's permission to Administrators, but the UAC prompt is only shown once, because when I allow access, it automatically saves my user as having permission.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple folder encryption be a much safer and easier to manage solution?

Comment: No because I want to run a script inside this folder and also, as soon as I decrypt the folder for seeing its contents, all programs running on the machine will be able to open it as well, as it will be a common folder.

Comment: So the only way to have this is if I create a new non-admin user, login with that user, and give the folder admin, or another user's permission?

Comment: Windows does not actually support what you want to do.  Any solutions would involve running third-party software, which of course, can by bypassed by any Administrator on the system. In fact even if Windows did support what you want, any Administrator, could give them access to the folder you attempted to protect. Yes; The only way to prevent a user from accessing a folder, is explicitly revoke their permissions to the folder, with the understand that any Administrator can explicitly give themselves permissions to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible, but you must not use Windows Explorer to access this folder. As you discovered, it will not elevate itself to access the folder but rather change the folder permissions. You cannot achieve the behavior you desire with Windows Explorer.

Instead, you could use a third-party Windows Explorer replacement like Double Commander which you would manually start elevated. Command Prompt and PowerShell can also be started elevated. All other software operating on the contents of this folder would also have to run elevated.

Running software elevated can pose a security risk. You should only do so when absolutely necessary.

Using a different (service) account without admin permissions is a better solution.